# C# create a browse for file property for a custom control

Tags: c#, file, properties, custom-controls

while I was authoring a custom theme/control I needed to create a property for that control in which the user selects an .ico file (A Windows Icon File). It's supposed to be like a Choose background property for the form. Accept, this is limited to a .ico file.
So far, I have this code:

```
private string IconLocation;
public string CustomIcon
{
    get
    {
        return IconLocation;
    }
    set
    {
        IconLocation = value;
    }
}
```

regardless to say, this doesn't work as i wanted, I also found this code:

```
[DefaultValue(""), Editor("System.Web.UI.Design.ImageUrlEditor, System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", typeof(UITypeEditor)), UrlProperty, WebSysDescription("Image_ImageUrl"), Bindable(true), WebCategory("Appearance")]
public virtual string ImageUrl
{
    get
    {
        string str = (string) this.ViewState["ImageUrl"];
        if (str != null)
        {
            return str;
        }
    return string.Empty;
    }
    set
    {
        this.ViewState["ImageUrl"] = value;
    }
}
```

gotten from: http://forums.asp.net/t/1335659.aspx

this doesn't work either, due to view-state being unavailable, so how do I implement a file choice for a custom property in normal c#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, figured it out, seems like there was no documentation, but this is how to do it:

```
private Icon IconLocation;
public Icon CustomIcon
{
    get
    {
        return IconLocation;
    }
    set
    {
        IconLocation = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried in vain to create my own UITypeEditor by deriving from one from `UrlEditor` as `ImgageUrlEditor` does and tried to use this one. However, this has absolutely no effect.

```
[SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Flags = SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode)]
public class IconUrlEditor : UrlEditor
{
    protected override string Filter
    {
        get
        {
            return "Icon Files (*.ico)|*.ico";
        }
    }
}
```

I also set the filter property of `UrlProperty`. This seems to have no effect as well.

```
public partial class WebUserControl1 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image1.ImageUrl = ImageUrl;
    }

    [Editor(typeof(IconUrlEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor)), UrlProperty("*.ico")]
    public virtual string ImageUrl { get; set; }
}
```

Either, I am missing something, or these filter properties are not used at all internally.

Comment: Note also that I do not assign the icon url to the ViewState directly, as the ViewState is not available at design time. Instead I just store it in the automatically implented property ImageUrl and load it in an Image control at Page_Load.